# How to manage thread synchronization in C++ for threads which need access to two different resources from a pool of resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

This program simulates multiple threads accessing different resources.
I have a pool of resources, in my case an array of bools : `bool res[6] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};`
I also have 6 different threads that are created, that all need to access two of these resources at a time :

```
T1 -> needs res[0] and res[1]
T2 -> needs res[1] and res[2]
T3 -> needs res[2] and res[3]
T4 -> needs res[3] and res[4]
T5 -> needs res[4] and res[5]
T6 -> needs res[0] and res[5]
```

When a thread uses a resource, it sets the bool to 0 and back to 1 when it's done. Ex : T1 sets res[0] and res[1] to 0, 'uses it' and sets both back to 1 afterwards.

I am unsure on how to use a mutex or a semaphore to prevent race conditions.

The obvious but slow way is to use a mutex to lock the whole section when a thread is using two resources and unlock it when it's done, preventing any other thread from taking any resource. The problem with this is some threads should be able to both run at the same time, ex: T1 and T3 do not share resources in common and therefore should be able to do there thing at the same time. On the flip-side, T1 and T2 should not be able to run at the same time as they share res[1]. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Here is something I have tried with semaphores for each resource, I think this solution works but I could be wrong:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <semaphore>
#include <chrono>
#include <syncstream>

bool el1[6]={1,1,1,1,1,1};

const int64_t tempsCreationObjetsMS = 3000;

std::binary_semaphore sem0{0}, sem1{0}, sem2{0}, sem3{0}, sem4{0}, sem5{0};

void creer_thread(std::string nom)
{
    if(nom == "coupe")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;
    
        if (el1[0] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 0" << std::endl;
            sem0.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[1] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 1" << std::endl;
            sem1.acquire();
        }

        el1[0] = 0;
        el1[1] = 0;

        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;

        el1[0] = 1;
        el1[1] = 1;

        sem0.release();
        sem1.release();
    }
    else if(nom=="epee")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;

        if (el1[1] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 1" << std::endl;
            sem1.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[2] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 2" << std::endl;
            sem2.acquire();
        }

        el1[1] = 0;
        el1[2] = 0;

        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;
        el1[1] = 1;
        el1[2] = 1;

        sem1.release();
        sem2.release();
    }
    else if(nom=="chandelier")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;

        if (el1[2] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 2" << std::endl;
            sem2.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[3] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 3" << std::endl;
            sem3.acquire();
        }

        el1[2] = 0;
        el1[3] = 0;
        
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;

        el1[2] = 1;
        el1[3] = 1;

        sem2.release();
        sem3.release();
    }
    else if(nom=="bague")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;

        if (el1[3] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 3" << std::endl;
            sem3.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[4] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 4" << std::endl;
            sem4.acquire();
        }

        el1[3] = 0;
        el1[4] = 0;

        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;

        el1[3] = 1;
        el1[4] = 1;

        sem3.release();
        sem4.release();
    }
    else if(nom=="table")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;

        if (el1[4] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 4" << std::endl;
            sem4.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[5] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 5" << std::endl;
            sem5.acquire();
        }

        el1[4] = 0;
        el1[5] = 0;

        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;

        el1[4] = 1;
        el1[5] = 1;

        sem4.release();
        sem5.release();
    }
    else if(nom=="porte")
    {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Je suis le thread " << nom << std::endl;

        if (el1[0] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 0" << std::endl;
            sem0.acquire();
        }
        if (el1[5] != 1)
        {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en attente de la resource 5" << std::endl;
            sem5.acquire();
        }

        el1[0] = 0;
        el1[5] = 0;
        
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " en creation." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tempsCreationObjetsMS));
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << nom << " cree." << std::endl;

        el1[0] = 1;
        el1[5] = 1;

        sem0.release();
        sem5.release();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread th1(creer_thread,"coupe");
    std::thread th2(creer_thread,"epee");
    std::thread th3(creer_thread,"chandelier");
    std::thread th4(creer_thread,"bague");
    std::thread th5(creer_thread,"table");
    std::thread th6(creer_thread,"porte");

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();
    th4.join();
    th5.join();
    th6.join();
}
```

Comment: This sounds a bit like [Dining Philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) (except that there are usually only 5 of them, but this doesn't change much).

Comment: A mutex per resource and a [scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) might be simplest

Comment: Instead of muteces, you could use `std::atomic<bool>`s or `std::atomic_flag`s. Since C++20, there is even a `wait()` and a `notify_one()` / `notify_all()`.

Comment: You can have six locks, as long as you always acquire them in the same order: otherwise, deadlock.

Comment: @user207421 _as long as you always acquire them in the same order_ or use [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) to acquire them.

Comment: you can put the threads in two groups. `T1`, `T3` and `T5` can work at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution depends on the nature of the resources but either a semaphore or mutex can be used and the speed would depend more on implementation.

I'd recommend using a mutex because it sounds like each resource is unique and each thread will need to wait for a specific resource. Each resource will need its own mutex that controls thread access to it. That way there is no need to lock other threads unless they want to use that specific resource.

Ex: Thread 1 is using resource 1 so it will lock the mutex for resource 1. If any other thread wants to use resource 1 it will have to check the mutex to see if its in use and then just wait until the mutex is unlocked by the thread using it(thread 1 in this case).

Also, the res boolean you've described is in theory a semaphore if you can guarantee atomic access to it (ie no race conditions). [See here for more about atomic access](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/atomic.htm). If each resource is not unique, meaning a thread only needs 2 at a time then a semaphore approach may be better.

I'd suggest doing more research about multithreading in general and looking at existing solutions such as [pthreads](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html) for c++ before trying to make this simulator.